# email sending from localhost in cakephp using emailcomponent

Tags: email, cakephp

```
<?php 

    class EmailsController extends AppController
    {
        var $uses=null;
        var $components=array(
                'Email'=>array(
                    'delivery'=>'smtp',
                    'smtpOptions'=>array(
                      'host'=>'ssl://smtp.google.com',
                      'username'=>'username@gmail.com',
                      'password'=>'password',
                      'port'=>465
                      )


        ));

         function sendEmail() {
            $this->Email->to = 'Neil <neil6502@gmail.com>';
            $this->Email->subject = 'Cake test simple email';
            $this->Email->replyTo = 'neil6502@gmail.com';
            $this->Email->from = 'Cake Test Account <neil6502@gmail.com>';
            //Set the body of the mail as we send it.
            //Note: the text can be an array, each element will appear as a
            //seperate line in the message body.
            if ( $this->Email->send('Here is the body of the email') ) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email sent');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email not sent');
            }
            $this->redirect('/');
            } 





    }


?>
```

above code is my controller responsible for sending emails...

but when i run this function `sendEmail()` using url `http://localhost/authentication/emails/sendemail`  it shows nothing not even single error or any response... complete blank page. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue a while ago. It might be that you need to change the `to` address into a value that holds *just* the address, so instead of `Name <email@example.com>` you should use `email@example.com`.

You can check for errors by logging (or debugging) the smtp errors with:

```
$this->log($this->Email->smtpError, 'debug');
```

or

```
debug($this->Email->smtpError);
```

Good luck. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Auf SMTP-Fehler prüfen */
 $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation (in english) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the Email Config to your email.php file located in **/app/Config/email.php** , if it doesn't exist **copy email.php.default to email.php,** Change the smtp settings there

```
public $smtp = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret'
);
```

**At the top of your Controller above class EmailsController extends AppController add,**

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

**Then in your function sendEmail() try,**

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'))
    ->to('you@example.com')
    ->subject('About')
    ->send('My message');
```

To **test emails** what I usually do is send them to the Cake Logs,

**In /app/Config/email.php, include: ( The log output should be /app/tmp/logs/debug.log )

```
public $test = array(
  'log' => true
);
```

Also doing this **add 'test' to your $Email variable** like,**

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case : I got a error message "SMTP server did not accept the password."

After that i follow the below link and issue has been resolved : 
Step1 : https://blog.shaharia.com/send-email-from-localhost-in-cakephp-using-cakeemail/
Step2 : [Sending Activation Email , SMTP server did not accept the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399202/sending-activation-email-smtp-server-did-not-accept-the-password)