# Sending Activation Email , SMTP server did not accept the password

Tags: cakephp, smtp, gmail, sendmail

I'm sending an email using CakePHP and I got an Error: `SMTP server did not accept the password`, along with an email in my inbox says that: `sign-in attempt blocked! , we recently blocked a sign-in attempt to your Google Account`.

Is that normal?

I'm using Xampp.

```
function sendActivationEmail($user_id)    
{   
    Debugger::dump($user_id);

    $user = $this->User->findById($user_id);

    if ($user==false) 
    {
        debug(__METHOD__." failed to retrieve User data for user.id: {$user_id}");
        return false;
    } 
    $this->set('username', $this->data['User']['username']);
    $this->Email->to = $user['User']['email'];
    $this->Email->subject = env('SERVER_NAME').'- Please confirm your email address';
    $this->Email->from = 'laurent@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->template = 'account_verification';
    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'port'=>'465',
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username'=>'laurent@gmail.com',
    'password'=>1234567
    );
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'text';  
    return $this->Email->send();

}
```

Comment: can you post your here code?

Comment: I've added the code up there ,what could be wrong ?

Comment: try to insert your password in ''. like this '123456'
are you using localhost? sometimes email() is not working in other version of xampp.

Comment: I've tried that before , and yes I'm using localhost but mostly its a gmail security issue as <burzum> has mentioned

Comment: yeah, I forgot that google function to mention. haha! good luck. (y)

Comment: Use another username and password only to check.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to allow "less secure" apps in your Google account settings:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

[image]

See this announcement as well http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html

**You should implement OAuth2 instead of weakening the security!**

Comment: I'm still getting :SMTP server did not accept the password. even after setting Access for less secure apps to Enable

Comment: @Exchanger13 I'm getting the same thing, did you find a solution?

Comment: This did the job! https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click the button 'Continue'.

Comment: I know I am quite late to the party, but, does anyone know the reasons why an app may be identified as a "less secure app?"

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that the field in 'username' => and 'password'=> is authenticate or valid. I had experienced the same issue and all I do is to go this link https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click the button 'Continue'.
make sure you're logged in in gmail using the 'username' and 'password' provided in your code. After that, try to send email again.

Comment: Nice. Worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the error `SMTP server did not accept the password.` . any idea about that?

Comment: Work for me Thank you for saving my time

Comment: Note that if you are logged in to multiple Gmai/Google accounts you may have to visit the specific page for the user. For example I was doing for number 2 user so I had to replace 0 with 2 in the url to make it https://accounts.google.com/b/2/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. in my case Password was not so strong. It contains username in password. I change the password and try again. it works.
*The other thing you can do that you can use other email address with strong password. make sure captcha is and less secure is enabled.  *

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha